# Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement Authenticate with Firebase on Android using a Phone Number  and its second step is to  add the dependency for Firebase Authentication to your app-level build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
<br>after adding it , I try to sync project with Gradle Files
and it showing error<br>Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0
<a href="openFile:/project/Mobileveridacetion/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a><br>Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0
<a href="openFile:/project/Mobileveridacetion/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: I suspect your gradle didn't successfully synced. Try Resync

Comment: after updating Google Repository. It work. successfully :)

Comment: Cool! cheers!  :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 10):

Go to **Tools > Android > SDK Manager** click on **SDK Tools** and update the following to their revision number :

- **Google Repository** (revision: 53)
- **Android SDK Platform-Tools** (revision: 26.0.0)

Answer (score 5):

Just go to SDK manager and update your Google Repository.
It will work. :)

Comment: This is frustrating. I thought they were going to be using the new `https://maven.google.com` going forward.